# Lost my Spanish ID (TIE) and I want to go to Italy

Tags: schengen, italy, spanish-residents

I'm on a student visa in Spain and I had a Spanish residence card or TIE but it was inside my wallet which was stolen. My visa is already expired and I want to travel to Italy but my TIE duplicate appointment isn't until January. Is it possible for me to just get an Autorización de Regreso for me to travel? Will they allow me to leave the country and come back with just this document? Will this document be accepted by the Italian immigration?

Comment: There is no immigration between Spain and Italy (or back) as long as your route does not leave the Schengen area. A complication could be boarding a plane, but again as long as it intra-Schengen I would expect no issues as long as you have some valid ID (your national passport). The worrying part could what would happen if you come across Italian police and they detain you, as you could have some extra trouble to show that you are legally in Schengen.